# Does Assets support the category image field

Tags: assets

I'm trying to attach category images from the edit category function in EE. I noticed that while adding an image category images only displays the EE file manager. I'm using Assets (S3) however as the main image source.

Does Assets support category images or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. You'd have to write an add-on that invoked the [Assets sheet](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/developers/sheet.html) on the category edit screen, but it's be tricky (injecting a bunch of javascript into the page essentially).

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd spare others from a little bit of false hope and lost time, and share a workaround that did not pan out:

My thought was to add a 'New Category Field' to the Categories I was interested in using Category Images in, using 'Assets' as the field type. Well, sadly 'Assets' is not an option there.

Unless there's some way of expanding which field types are allowed as 'Category Fields' ..?

Rats.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to just put the full Amazon S3 (or Cloudfront) url into the category description, then call in on the page like so:

```
{if category_description}<img src="{category_description}" alt="{category_name}" />{/if}
```

It's hacky but it works.